# ios, submit .IPA file to the app store

Tags: ios

another developer created the .ipa file using his provisioning profile and certificates.
he sent the ,IPA file to me.

Can I submit the app/.ipa file under my account ??

Answer (score 0):

No, You Can't, Since the App ID is generated from another account

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly submit the .ipa file to your account. However, you can resign the .app file and submit it to the apple store.

Re-sign the .app file with your distribution certificate and submit it to the apple store. This [link](http://furbo.org/2008/11/12/the-final-test/) will help you.